# Find a polynomial $p$ of degree $3$ if its value in $4$ points is given

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Find a polynomial $p$ of degree $3$ such that

\begin{align*}
p(−4) &= −142, \\
p(1) &= −2, \\
p(−5) &= −242, \\
p(4) &= 10.
\end{align*}

Then use your polynomial to approximate $p(2)$.

\begin{align*}
p(x) &= ?, \\
p(2) &= ?.
\end{align*}

I can't find this sort of question in the textbook so I'm having trouble.
Please teach me how to solve this question and, perhaps, fill in point 2?

Thank you.

Comment: Lagrange's polynomials? Never heard of them?

Comment: "Approximate" is the wrong word here. "Use your formula to calculate $p(2)$" would be more accurate, since you're working with that polynomial all the time; you're not approximating some other function $f$ with $p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You general cubic has the form $p(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$.

Plugging in the four points will give you four equations in the four unknowns $\{a,b,c,d\}$.

For example, $p(1) = -2 \Rightarrow -2 = a + b + c + d$.

Solve that system of equations however you know best!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Find constants $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ such that the polynomial
$$a(x-1)(x+5)(x-4)+b(x+4)(x+5)(x-4)+c(x+4)(x-1)(x-4)+d(x+4)(x-1)(x-5)$$
takes on the desired values.

For example, to compute $a$, we want $a(-4-1)(-4+5)(-4-4)=-142$.